# how to swap the position of a linked image with the text?

Tags: html

How can I swap the position between the linked image and the text?
I want the image to be on the right and the text on the left, but what appears is the image on the left and the text on the right

[I want to swap this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckqxd.png)

```
<div class="language-switcher col border-left">
  <a href="#" class="bahasa">
    <img class="id-flag ml-3 mr-3 mr-lg-3 mb-1" src="Front-End/images/Icon/Indonesia Flag@2x.png" alt="Bahasa Indonesia" />
    ID
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="english col ml-3 border-left">
    <img class="en-flag ml-3 mr-3 mr-lg-3 mb-1" src="Front-End/images/Icon/GBR Flag@2x.png" alt="English" />
    EN
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you swap anchor tag position as per your need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the order of the children of the anchor element:

```
<div class="language-switcher col border-left">
  <a href="#" class="bahasa">
    ID
    <img class="id-flag ml-3 mr-3 mr-lg-3 mb-1" src="Front-End/images/Icon/Indonesia Flag@2x.png" alt="Bahasa Indonesia" />
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="english col ml-3 border-left">
    EN
    <img class="en-flag ml-3 mr-3 mr-lg-3 mb-1" src="Front-End/images/Icon/GBR Flag@2x.png" alt="English" />
  </a>
</div>
```